# PHP e Ajax: Retirar aspas do resulado do ajax

Tags: php, ajax

O resultado está vindo com aspas e não sei como retirar.
No PHP:

```
if ($finalImage) {
echo json_encode(sucesso);
exit;
}

if (!$finalImage) {
echo json_encode('erro');
exit;
}
```

No ajax:

```
        success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    if(result == "sucesso") {
        mopageFix();
        $('.mopageFix').load('data/photo/amostraCrop.php');
    if(result == "erro") {
        mopage();
        $('.mopage').load('data/admdata.php?crop=no');
    }
```

O console.log(result) está resultando: "sucesso"

Pergunta: Como retirar as aspas de `json_encode(sucesso)` OU como colocar aspas em `(result == "sucesso")`?

Obrigado!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pq não coloca apenas `echo "sucesso";` e `echo "erro";`?

Comment: Se você colocar `echo "sucesso";` vai retornar apenas `sucesso` sem aspas, e no JS compara como já está fazendo: `result == "sucesso"`

Comment: Talvez seja necessário usar .trim() no resultado: `if(result.trim() == "sucesso")`... porque se a string `sucesso` vier com algum espaço antes ou depois (ou nos dois), o `if` não vai validar.

Comment: É isso mesmo Sam... o trim funcionou! Eu postei a imagem do console.log, dê uma "olhada procê" ver que há muito espaço... e minha falta de experiência nem me fez notar... e olha que "fucei" bastante... kkkk... vacilo... Obrigado meu "amiguin"!

Comment: Para que usar `json_encode()` nesse caso, se você nem está passando array, e porque vc não faz apenas `echo "sucesso";`??? Por acaso você não pretendia passar uma variável assim? `json_encode($sucesso);`?

Comment: json_encode é para retornar em formato json: exemplo `json_encode(['a' => 'b']);`  irá retonar: `{"a": "b"}` e no javascript, vc captura através de uma função anônima, por exemplo o retorno: data.a, irá imprimir "b". no caso o seu `result`.

Comment: Poxa Ivan, obrigado pela gentileza! Consegui resolver com o trim e já retirei o json_encode(). Bom demais aprender... novamente obrigado e que Deus te ilumine!